# jQuery do something on one of events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, redundancy

I'd like to use jQuery to perform one single operation when **one of the events** happen, rather how to optimize this code:

```
$("#selector").on('click', function(){
 alert(1);
});

$("#selector").on('hover', function(){
 alert(1);
});

$("#selector").on('blur', function(){
 alert(1);
});
```

You see where I'm going with this. Basically it's one same functions but it's only the different triggers. Is there any way to stop me being redundant and wrap all this more simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With multiple selector chaining

```
$('#element').on('click hover blur', function() {
    ...
});
```

---

You can also select multiple classes:

```
$('#foo, #bar, #element').on('click hover blur', function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: You're a beast! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#element').on('click hover blur', function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: And what about multiple selectors?
I mean what if I only what the "click" trigger, but "#element1" and "#element2" to be triggered on.